# Show content title in front page and full page when click

Tags: views

I want to add comments,post,follow to full node, it work with little sucees with view but i was unable to add comments, post, follow to full article post.

I have a content type called News it will only be showing article title in front page and article full node when clicked. The full node posted will have Add coment, Post, follow

The main problem now is how can i add comments, Post, follow likn to full node.

[image: full node in view]

[image: title in image]

Comment: Didn't I already help you with this?

Comment: yes, but when i apply all these settings in view it only apply to article title not full post of article

Comment: Just follow these tutorials depending on what module you choose to install.[ShareThis Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=drupal+share+this+module) or [Add To Any Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Yjx7aEc4js)